# asp.net load random

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

we want this to load a new question when you press it, but we get a syntax error

```
{"Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'."}
```

heres the code. we use the db thats in visual studio

```
private void loadgrid()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Question] ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = rd;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  That database uses `TOP` rather than `LIMIT` and you don't want `RAND()` you want `NEWID()`:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 2 * FROM [Question] ORDER BY NEWID()";
```

The `RAND()` piece is tricky.  The code will execute, but `RAND()` is only calculated once per query, so the results won't really be random.

Comment: Oh man, ty. Late night SO lurking worth it. Have so many places to use this I wish i knew it months ago T_T

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you can use `TOP`:

```
SELECT top 2 * FROM [Question] ORDER BY RAND();
```